# Raman Rotational Effect for Diatomic Molecules

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, molecular-dynamics, isotopes, raman-spectroscopy

I have a doubt about Rotational Raman effect phenomena. As we know for Rotational effect the heavier of the two isotopes the band levels goes down between the two (which is most heavy).

So say for H2 and D2, spacing between 1st stokes and anti stokes distance between them is 12B, does the seperation changes? Like in Rotational effect, the B has mass term as inversely proportional, do the same happens with Rotational Raman too.